# I logged in and saw two ip's on the same device (enp3s0). DHCP won't work well. How do I resolve this?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, ubuntu-20.04

While ssh-logging in on a 20.0.4 ubuntu server using the hostname I saw this:

```
  IPv4 address for docker0: 172.17.0.1
  IPv4 address for enp3s0:  10.0.0.10
  IPv4 address for enp3s0:  10.0.0.14
  IPv6 address for enp3s0:  fdca:93c9:a381:2:15f0:9cf1:30bc:e16e
  IPv6 address for enp3s0:  fdca:93c9:a381:2:468a:5bff:fe2c:d0b4
```

I believe this is wrong, because:

- Firstly I have the DHCP server set to hand out (only) the 10.0.0.10 address, it should never give out 10.0.0.14
- Secondly I believe I have DHCP enabled on this client. (Not entirely sure, I am not 100% used to CLI-only linux)

**What steps can I take to resolve this?**

Extra info: I started looking into what was wrong after I saw homebridge complaining:

```
[4/2/2021, 2:00:41 PM] Homebridge v1.3.4 (Homebridge 3D9C) is running on port 51451.
[4/2/2021, 2:00:41 PM] Error: Service name is already in use on the network
    at Registry._onProbeComplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/bonjour-hap/lib/Registry.js:108:27)
    at Prober.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/bonjour-hap/lib/Prober.js:67:10)
    at Prober.onMDNSresponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/bonjour-hap/lib/Prober.js:61:102)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/multicast-dns/index.js:49:43)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at UDP.onMessage (dgram.js:919:8)
[4/2/2021, 2:00:41 PM] Got SIGTERM, shutting down Homebridge...
[4/2/2021, 2:00:46 PM] [RPi] goodbye
```

I then checked what vlans were routed to this switch port, and I saw 'all'. I changed that to 'only the 10.0.0.0/24 network', since a [github issue](https://github.com/homebridge/homebridge/issues/2031) suggested disabling mdns reflection and I had a reflection from 10.0.0.0/24 to 10.0.3.0/24, however I'm not sure this is related.

Furthermore, this machine got the ip 10.0.0.14 assigned in the past for migration purposes, but has been using 10.0.0.10 for a while. I am not sure if it has been using 10.0.0.14 as well for a while.

Output of `ifconfig -a`:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::468a:5bff:fe2c:d0b4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdca:93c9:a381:2:15f0:9cf1:30bc:e16e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fdca:93c9:a381:2:468a:5bff:fe2c:d0b4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 44:8a:5b:2c:d0:b4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3403076  bytes 5137141793 (5.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1597138  bytes 93321020 (93.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

[image: Homebridge settings showing 10.0.0.14]

Side note: Homebridge uses 'Bonjour HAP'

```
user@machine:/etc/network$ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 12 09:04 if-down.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  4 06:36 if-post-down.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  4 06:36 if-pre-up.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 12 09:04 if-up.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 11 21:18 interfaces
user@machine:/etc/network$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

Comment: You may need to be more specific by stating the device you are facing this problem with.

Comment: @Ruby I hope I clarified it a bit more. What else can I test/add to the question?

Comment: Can I see the output from `cat /etc/network/interfaces` ?.

Comment: It's empty, added info in post.

Comment: You may try manual removal of the unwanted address using `addr` command `sudo ip addr del 10.0.0.10 dev enp3s0`